# Open a image of a Google Doc in in another window

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Doc with images. I would like to open a selected image in a page in another window (the google doc is a role playing game scenario and I want to show the image to my players on a second screen).

I have created a sidebar with a google script and I am able to show the selected image in this sidebar.
Now, I don't know how to open a new window (or connect a existing window) and send the image data to this window.

I start by trying to use the "PresentationRequest", but I have the error "PresentationRequest is not defined" on the init...

```js
presentationRequest = new PresentationRequest('receiver.html');
```

My source :
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/04/present-web-pages-to-secondary-attached-displays

For information (and if it helps someone) how I send the image to the sidebar page:

```js
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var selection = doc.getSelection();

if (selection) {
  var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
  var e = elements[0].getElement();

  if (e.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
    var blobImg = e.asInlineImage().getBlob();
    return 'data:' + blobImg.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blobImg.getBytes());
  }
}
```

The HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style type="text/css">
      .tailMax {
        max-width: 260px;
        max-height: 260px;
      }

      .centre {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="formJdr">
      <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <button type="button" id="btnAffImg" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afficheImg).selectImg()">Afficher</button>
        <label id="lblImg">Sélectionnez une image</label>
      </div>
      <img id="img" class="tailMax centre"/>
    </form>
    <script>
    function afficheImg(valeur) {
      if (typeof value === "string"){
        // Message
        afficheMessage(valeur);
      }
      else {
        try {
          // Image to show
          afficheMessage("");
          document.getElementById("img").src = valeur;
        }
        catch(error) {
          afficheMessage(error);
        }
      }
    }

    function afficheMessage(message) {
      document.getElementById("lblImg").innerHTML = message;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use a Chrome browser.

Do you think it is possible?

Comment: Your html code? And browser used?

Comment: I have edited my message...

Comment: To future viewers, Currently,  Google iframe sandbox doesn't have `allow-presentation` and hence this is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the help of Ziganotschka, I update my javascript code for this.
Now I can change the image in the new window.
Just some improvements to make on the opening of this window and it will be good.

```html
<script>
var affichage;

function afficheImg(valeur) {
  if (typeof value === "string"){
    afficheMessage(valeur);
  }
  else {
    try {
      afficheMessage("");

      var image = document.getElementById("img");
      image.src = valeur;
      affichage.document.body.innerHTML = "";
      affichage.document.write(image.outerHTML);
    }
    catch(error) {
      afficheMessage(error);
    }
  }
}

function afficheMessage(message) {
  document.getElementById("lblImg").innerHTML = message;
}

window.onload = function() {
  affichage = window.open("", '_blank');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `try` statement as following:

```
        try {
          // Image to show
          afficheMessage("");
          var image=document.getElementById("img");
          image.src = valeur;                                           
          var w = window.open("", '_blank');
         w.document.write(image.outerHTML);                                   

        }
```

`var w = window.open("", '_blank'); w.document.write(image.outerHTML);` allows you to open a new window and then write the image as bytearray into it.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should be able to reuse the same window to update the image ...